# JQuery display an alert after submitting a form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created a form which is working; I would like to create an alert when a user submits to say that their request has been successfully added. This is the code that I have:

```
<form id="target" method="post">
   <label for="firstName">First Name*:</label>
   <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php 
   if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) 
   { ?>

   <script>
    $("#target").submit(function(event){
    alert("Entry has been succesfully added!");
    event.preventDefault();
    });
   </script>

 <?php 
 } ?>
```

Comment: so what problem are you facing?

Comment: the alert won't show up

Comment: your script never gets output to the page since it is inside a condition which is not satisfied

Comment: The condition is being satisfied. If i take the script off and just php echo, it works. But i'd rather have an alert as a notification

Comment: Your condition gets satisfied when you click on submit, but the script should be present on your page when the page loads for it to work

Comment: <?php 
       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
       { ?>
    
       <script>
        
        alert("Entry has been succesfully added!");
       
       
       </script>
    
     <?php 
     } 
     
     ?>

Comment: Or use ajax...your page gets reloaded, the rest of the js will not work... (submit button already clicked)

Comment: Ajax is the solution here. There are many tutorials yet on the web.

Comment: OK will read up on AJAX. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put the alert inside a `.submit()` handler. The PHP code runs after the form is submitted. When the form is submitted, the page is reloaded with what the PHP returns, so it should return a script that just performs the alert.

```
<form id="target" method="post">
   <label for="firstName">First Name*:</label>
   <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<?php 
   if (isset($_POST['submit']) && $statement) 
   { ?>
   <script>
    alert("Entry has been succesfully added!");
   </script>

 <?php 
 } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap modal to acheive that

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
         rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script>


 <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">form submission</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p> your data submitted successfully </p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#target").submit(function(event){ 
           event.preventDefault();
           $('#myModal').modal('show');
       }):
   })
</script>
```

Comment: why post a completely different solution rather than correcting the OP's code. Besides, the OP might not know bootstrap and modals and this wouldn't be helpful to them

Comment: @Silencer310 i think he is looking for a solution that let him notify the user with the submissions

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this..

```
<form id="target" method="post">
<label for="firstName">First Name*:</label>
<input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script>
$("#target").submit(function(event){
alert("Entry has been succesfully added!");
event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```